# free Memory in c

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I have a doubt regarding:

```
void *a = malloc(40);
free(a);
```

If I consider that malloc(40) allocates 40 bytes of memory and returns the address of this memory and then free(a) deallocates/frees this memory **but doesn't do anything with the bit pattern residing in that memory**. So, supposedly this same memory is allocated to say void *b, then on printing the value at address pointed to by b gives me the same value that was residing or it gives me a garbage value and why?

Comment: It's not a "doubt". It's a *question*. SO is a question-answer site, not a skeptics' blog.

Comment: You can't rely on anything at all in the situation you're describing.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I didn't even notice the "doubt" part, I'm used to emailing with guys in India whose doubts shall be clarified ASAP... :-}

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: I've been noticing this for a very long time, but it just never makes sense to me... You can doubt Jesus (if your name is Thomas), but you can't doubt `malloc`!

Comment: @FrerichRaabe while I know where you're coming from, I have to agree with Kerrek, that has always been a pet peeve of mine

Comment: @KerrekSB: I meant I have a question. I am sorry if it hurt you :P

Comment: @Mike: I concur, I'll now move on and do the needful. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you have this situation in mind:

```
void * a = malloc(40);
free(a);
void * b = malloc(40);

assert(a == b);
```

This is of course entirely plausible, since memory is likely to be reused.

However, since `a == b`, you've answered your own question: The value of `b` is identical to the value of `a`!

I believe that you've asked the wrong question, and that you are *actually* interested in comparing the *memory pointed to by `b`*. That's a whole different kettle of fish. Anything could have happened in between the two `malloc` calls. Nothing is guaranteed. The memory pointed to by the return value of a `malloc` call is *uninitialized*, and you cannot make *any* assumptions about its content. It stands to reason that the memory will not have changed in a typical, optimized C library, but there's no guarantee. A "safe" runtime environment may well choose to overwrite freed or allocated memory with a specific test pattern to allow better detection of invalid accesses.

Comment: Even without a "safe" runtime that goes out of its way to write a particular value, it's not very difficult to invent a memory allocator that uses the first few bytes of each free block for some of its own housekeeping information. Typically the housekeeping for an allocated block doesn't use any less space than that for a free block, though.

Answer (score 3):

It can give you any value.
C/C++ standards do not mandate the value to be anything specific. In technical terms the value of any uninitialized variable/memory is **Indeterminate**.

In short, Your program should not rely on this value to be anything specific and if it does then it is non-portable.

Answer (score 0):

Its not guaranteed anything. Printing block you got from **malloc** may print previous data, or may not. There is many things that can alter next malloc block(so next address will be different) or alter old memory block itself, too.

Answer (score 0):

free will often modify the memory you're freeing.

It's a common trick, especially in debug mode, for free to overwrite memory with some fixed pattern to make it easier to tell if you're double freeing memory, or just manipulating freed memory.

Likewise malloc might overwrite memory with a different pattern to make it obvious that the memory is uninitialised.

Answer (score 0):

malloc and free are C style memory management rather than C++. C++ alternatives are new and delete operators. As for the bit pattern remaining in the memory after free(), yes, it's the same bit pattern. If you want to manually delete the bit pattern, you can use memset() or ZeroMemory() if you write WinApi code.

Answer (score 0):

It will give you some garbage value as function **free()** will set the specified bytes to some pattern which will make it known to the memory that the bytes are freed and uninitialized. Having said so, it is very unlikely and highly improbable that you will encounter a case defined in your question. Even if you will get allocated the same bytes again, believe me, you will by no means recognize them :-)

AFAIK, **free()** generally sets the memory to **0xFE 0xEE with Visual Studio** which roughly means that the memory was allocated but now is freed. These value are known as **Sentinel Values** which means that the heap is still owned by the process but not in use. Memory which are freed from the process will show you **"?? ??"**.

Answer (score -1):

First, the code is not c++ but plain c.

The reason is, that `free()` / `delete` exist there to so the system can **note** that the memory region is again available for allocation.

Why should it do anything beyond ?

This is a security issue, however. I believe some security-oriented modern systems do zero the memory before giving it to an application. Then if you use `malloc()` for the first time you will get an equivalent to [calloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/). Never the less, if you happen to free the memory and then allocate it again might be able to read your own data.

The plain reason for such behaviour is simple. Zeroing memory would be time consuming and you can do it by hand. Actually it has `O(n)` complexity. If you write a number cruncher that reuses its memory, you do not care what you get in there after `malloc()` because most likely you should be overwriting it, and you definitely do not want your FLOPS to be negatively affected by unnecessary `memset()` upon calling `free()`.

If you want to be sure that nothing can read the memory after you call `free` you need to use `memset(a, 0, SIZE)` before calling `free()`.